# Check if class is sublass of another class

Tags: c#, .net

Hey I have a problem checking whether a class is subclass of another class or not. I have a method for this:

```
private bool IsSubclassOfRawGeneric(Type generic, Type toCheck)
    {
        while (toCheck != null && toCheck != typeof(object)) {
            var cur = toCheck.IsGenericType ? toCheck.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : toCheck;
            if (generic == cur) {
                return true;
            }
            toCheck = toCheck.BaseType;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The instance I want to check is of type `X : FooViewModelBase<Y>` and I'm passing `typeof(FooViewModelBase<Y>)` as first parameter. But still the compare returns false and I cannot see why, the name and everything of the types (in loop 2) are the same... Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you please provide how is your class look like. Not detail just level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that line:

```
toCheck.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
```

When you pass `X` to check, in second while iteration method call `toCheck.GetGenericTypeDefinition()` will return `FooViewModelBase<>` - but comparing it to `generic` variable which is of type`FooViewModelBase<Y>` will always return false.

Possible solution, written before `while`:

```
generic = generic.IsGenericType ? generic.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : generic;
```